# Getting a Mailbox unavailable. Too many invalid recipients error

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

Our application sends out emails using the

```
new SmtpClient(smtpServer).Send(message);
```

We are making sure that the smtpServer is valid, the message has To and From addresses, a subject and a body. If any of these are missing, we would log an exception before even attempting to send a message.

But the application frequently fails with the below exception.

**Email Fail: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Too many invalid recipients.**

Now, please note that the email send functionality is not failing always. For the same "To" address, it fails, may be about half the times. So, if the application tries sending out emails 100 times, we are getting some 40+ failures with the same message.

I have already validated that the To address and the From address exists. We are seeing this issue since last month when we shifted from Outlook to Gmail.
Here is the code.

```
if (fromAddress.Length == 0)
                fromAddress = Resources.FromAddress;

            if (toAddress.Length == 0) return "To Address is Required.";


            if (smtpServer.Length == 0)
                smtpServer = Resources.SMTPServer;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpServer))
                return "SMTP sever not specified";


            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

            //set the addresses
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
            string[] toAdds = toAddress.Split(';');
            short i = 0;
            foreach (string address in toAdds)
            {
               if(i==0) mailMessage.To.Add(address); else  mailMessage.CC.Add(address);
                i++;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bcc))
            {
                string[] bccAddresses = bcc.Split(';');

                foreach (string address in bccAddresses)
                {
                    mailMessage.Bcc.Add(address);
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc))
            {
                string[] ccAddresses = cc.Split(';');

                foreach (string address in ccAddresses)
                {
                    mailMessage.CC.Add(address);
                }
            }

            if (subject.Length > 0)
                mailMessage.Subject = subject;

            mailMessage.Body = sBody;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
            emailClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Any directions?

Comment: `Feroz` this can happen for a number of reasons.. if you have individual emails and one of them has an invalid hostname in their email address, or if you have not parsed the recipients list properly.. perhaps you have 2 email address colliding for example `tomthumb@aol.commarrK@gmail.com` and there is no proper separator.. the best thing I would suggest is to set break points process the large list and see which email(s) it fails on and inspect the value.. it's probably something so simple..

Comment: also without exposing the actual recipients email addresses to us could you give an exact example of the emails masking them or changing them ...

Comment: We have just one email address in "To" and one in "CC". Something like "axxxxs@txxxxk.com" in To and "axxxxk@rxxxxd.com" in CC and the From address is like Axxxxs@rxxxxd.com

Comment: This has become a difficult one to crack since all the emails are being sent to the same "To", same "CC" and from the same "From" addresses and some of them are failing. The angle of Outlook Vs Gmail is also interesting since the complaints started coming in at around the same time when the company shifted from Outlook to Gmail.

Comment: show the code of how you are sending multiple emails and how you are assigning it's delimited separator.. for example are you using `,` or `;` for the email separator.. and also are you trimming or getting the substring position of the last email which you would not have to use the ending separator so it should looks something like this in your inspector
`"axxxxs@txxxxk.com;""axxxxk@rxxxxd.com"` in the CC portion

Comment: if you are using a `List<T>` to house the email addresses then you could this is even easier.. I will wait to see what your code looks like before I provide a more robust fix for you..

Comment: Updated the post to show the code. I'm not the developer of this. Just doing the fixes. So, can't rewrite it. Can just fix it if there is anything wrong. Also, since the "To" and CC addresses have just one email address in them, I think we need not worry about separators.

Comment: when you are in the debugger what does this look like when you inspect it ` mailMessage.To` I would also think about replacing the split with something like this `var ccAddresses = string.Join(";", what ever list holds cc email address)`

Comment: Oh and since you mentioned that you switched from outlook to GMAIL what is the PORT and Smtp settings that you are using.. it helps if you provide all relevant code also verify if GMAIL uses `;` or `,` for their separator ..I bets that's the issue ..Outlook uses `;`

Comment: `Can just fix it if there is anything wrong.` well that's not a complete rewrite however if a fix requires a rewrite don't you think it's best to rewrite..? I am confused on that statement ...

Answer (score 0):

If the same email with the same sender and recipients is sometimes accepted, sometimes rejected by the SMTP server, it may be the result of a server antispam policy. For example :

- [Directory Harvest Attack Prevention (DHAP)](https://support.google.com/postini/answer/1753166?hl=en) : which causes a "550 Too many invalid recipients" error when exceeding a number of RCPT TO commands over a given period of time.
- Quotas : a limit on the number of mails that a mailbox/IP can send per minute/second to prevent spamming.

You can validate if the SMTP server settings are the cause of your problem by (temporarily) :

- whitelisting the IP address of your SMTP client
- disabling any quota/antispam Policy applied to your sender's mailbox

If that doesn't solve your problem, then use a tool like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to record the SMTP dialog and check exactly what email addresses are sent in the RCPT TO command, and in which cases the SMTP Server rejects them. Then, post it here.